# How to create a trail behind figure - BIG WORLD [2D, LIBGDX, JAVA]

Tags: java, libgdx, 2d

**Hello,**
Ido this in LIBGDX.

I creating a game that should have a fairly large world. My map has a resolution of 2048 X 2048 pixels and character has a size of 32x32 pixels. The camera looks at the world from above (classic 2D - old GTA). And i would like that my character left behind a trail in this world. Character moving already on created trail moves faster. My first idea was that I would repaint texture after which he walked , but it was quite difficult for the CPU.
I had a texture with which I tiled the entire map. I drew into individual tiles with "pixmap.fillCircle()" and so I leaved traces. <-- bad idea 
It should be a multiplayer game and the trail should help players find other players.

**How to do it better? More powerful?**

**Thank you for your advice....**

Answer (score 0):

In the end I'll try to do it like in minecraft. With chunks.

**Thanks**